# How to assign the source of a img tag to be the state of a component?

Tags: html, reactjs, web-component

I have a react project where I have a component that is currently showing a picture. There is also a button:

```
import React from 'react';

class Pokemon extends React.Component {

    state = {
        text: "./blank.png"
    };

    handleButton = (e) => {
        console.log("e: ",e);
        this.setState( {
            text: "./pikachupic.png"
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div class="container-fluid" >
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col" style={{ background: "gray", color: "white" }}>
                        <button onClick={this.handleButton}>Show Pokemon</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col" style={{ background: "black", color: "white" }}>
                        <h3>Pokemon Description</h3>
                        <img src={require("./pikachupic.png")}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Pokemon;
```

However what I want to do is to start with a blank image, and as soon as the user clicks the button, the pokemon image shows up. So I  have a state that starts with "./blank.png" and as soon as the button is clicked, it changes to "./pikachupic.png". I tried to change the following line

```
<img src={require("./pikachupic.png")}/>
```

to this:

```
<img src={require(this.state.text)}/>
```

but it threw errors after I made the change.

Error: Cannot find module './blank.png'

What is the correct syntax to assign the value of this.state.text to the source of the img tag?

Comment: How the error looks like ?

Comment: @dqlgnoleht edited question to include error. And yes, there is a document named blank.png in the same dir

Comment: The problem is the module import, not the syntax of setting img url, did you use `create-react-app` to generate project and stick with default webpack configuration ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<img src={require( `${ this.state.text }` )} />
```

or this:

```
<img src={require( "" + this.state.text )} />
```

since require needs a string, so you can't pass in the raw value

Comment: Quite surprise but it works, +1, I think `this.state.text` is string from very begining, why we need that parsing @Jayce444 ?

Comment: @dqlgnoleht I'm not entirely sure, it's kind of a quirk of `require` I believe. It requires a static string when it's resolved, so you can't directly use a variable but can concatenate it with a string, which will return a string. It's weird lol :P

Comment: why is require even used here If you already know the path to the image?

Comment: @JonB because when the app builds, the image will be at a different path. So you use `require` and a file loader and that will resolve to the correct path and file name after the app builds

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use the state value as your img src value, I renamed the state variable sorry but my OCD couldn't allow it to be just 'text' :D

```js
import React from 'react';

class Pokemon extends React.Component {

    state = {
        imgSrc: "./blank.png"
    };

    handleButton = (e) => {
        console.log("e: ",e);
        this.setState( {
            imgSrc: "./pikachupic.png"
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div class="container-fluid" >
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col" style={{ background: "gray", color: "white" }}>
                        <button onClick={this.handleButton}>Show Pokemon</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col" style={{ background: "black", color: "white" }}>
                        <h3>Pokemon Description</h3>
                        <img src={this.state.imgSrc}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Pokemon;
```